# Can't run foreman-installer on CentOS 7

Tags: puppet, centos7, foreman, puppet-dashboard

I'm trying to install foreman on CentOS 7 to work with Puppet 4.5. After performing all the steps from the manual I can't run foreman-installer.

```
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$ sudo foreman-installer
Could not get default values, check log file at /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman.log for more information
```

I got the following information from the log:

```
Evaluation Error: Unknown variable: '::domain'. at /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/puppet/manifests/params.pp:48:26 on node puppetmaster
Could not get default values, cannot continue
```

My environment:
CentOS 7 x86_64

- ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
- puppet 4.5.3

Maybe someone can advice me some working dashboard?

Comment: Have you checked if your hostname (e.g. cat /etc/hostname) is a FQDN?

Comment: I set equal hostnames for "facter fqdn" and "hostname -f" and it almost worked. I got the following error in the end.

"Evaluation Error: Unknown variable: 'default_user'. at /usr/share/foreman-installer/modules/xinetd/manifests/params.pp:69:6 on node puppetmaster"

Comment: Do you have `strict_variables` enabled in your puppet.conf? If so, try disabling it.